# @font-face Isn't Working, Help Needed

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm doing everything right according to w3schools.com, but my @font-face font won't work! What am I doing wrong? This is my code with CSS:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: title;
    src: url('peach-sundress.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="box">
    <h1 align="center" style="font-family: title;">Keegan Brown Photography</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Try this example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Comment: This is example does not work. This is my code now:

Comment: `@font-face{
  font-family: "title";
  src: url('peach-sundress.ttf');
 }`

Comment: and: `.box{
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px white;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 1px silver;
  opacity: 0.85;
  font-family: "title";
 }` @Alex

Comment: But, it still doesn't work @Alex

Comment: Oh i'm stupid, @Vohuman ; .ttf only works with iOS, and Android, and Safari. Do you guys happen to know where to get fonts with all of the types (aka woff, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the format separately unless you are using a bunch of different source files for your font for different browser support. Also you need some quotes on your font family, try this;

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'title';
  src: url('peach-sundress.ttf');
}
```

then use it like this

```
font-family:'title', sans-serif;
```

The sans serif is to provide a fallback, just in case. You can remove that if you don't want it.